# Why RabbitMQ + Ubuntu 18.04 (fresh install) loose all users/data after restart?

Tags: rabbitmq, reboot

Ubuntu 18.04, updated & upgraded.
RabbitMQ as per current version using RabbitMQ tutorial for installation.

Machine running on ESXI so no interference from a hardware.

After fresh installation, I have added new test user, assigned admin & access to queues etc.

Then I've logged in and created new admin user & assigned everything (same setup works perfectly well on Windows, tried ~ 2 servers + 3 dev machines, none of them had any issue with loosing data).

After rebooting all users are gone. (beside guest)

There was a bug for it, but it supposed to be solved like 2 years ago...

Anyone is using this on Ubuntu ?

```
rabbitmqctl add_user test test
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"
reboot
```

= The user is lost.

To install I've used:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting... After reboot, I've tried to add it again. This time it was saved.

I guess it has something to do with binding RabbitMQ instance.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem recently :

In my case the hostname had been changed after the RabbitMQ instance started.

As the configuration uses the hostname to identify the instance, after restart a new configuration was used. The previous configuration still exists in /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbitmq@old_host_name .